# Mastering Telekinetic Discipline?

Tags: rogue-trader, character-advancement

The book says about mastering a psychic discipline:

*Once a psyker has purchased 8 psychic techniques from a
single Discipline, he has attained mastery of that Discipline,
and the Psy Rating for all Fettered Psychic Strength uses of
techniques from that Discipline gain a +1 bonus. This has
no additional effect on the Unfettered or Push Psy Rating of
the psyker.*

But the Telekinetic discipline only has 7 techniques, then how can you attain mastery of that discipline? (Telepathy has 9 techniques, and Divination 8)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Telekinetic discipline has 7 force techniques (as listed in Table 6-15) and a basic technique, Mind Over Matter (p171): this gives a total of 8 powers. They just haven't listed the basic technique in the table, which would lead to some confusion about there only being 7 powers.

Comment: Thanks! Now, Mind Over Matter has to be purchased? How do you acquire it?

Comment: You get Mind Over Matter when you acquire access to the Telekinesis Discipline; you get it for free as a "starting power".

Comment: So, when purchasing any of the Telekinetic Discipline abilities, right?

Comment: You should have picked the Telekinesis Discipline as part of character generation. From that, you get Mind Over Matter. This goes the same for the other basic techniques in the other disciplines; as long as you pick a discipline, you get the basic technique. Look at it being less about the "purchasing" of 8 powers, but "having" 8 powers leads to mastery; from that, as soon as you have all 8 powers, you've mastered Telekinesis.

Comment: Hold on, look at the errata:

Discipline Mastery (page 159): The Basic Technique for a 
Discipline does count towards the number of powers required 
to acquire Discipline Mastery. 

If basic techniques don't count to Discipline Mastery, we're having a big problem here (only 7 non-basic Telekinetic skills!)

Comment: Read the errata statement more carefully. It DOES count towards mastery.