# Do basic techniques and special powers count towards a discipline mastery?

Tags: psionics, rogue-trader

Once a psyker has acquired 8 abilities of the same discipline he earns the discipline mastery, which gives him an extra point of psy-rating when using abilities of that discipline.

The Telepathy Discipline has the Basic Technique: Thought Sending and the Special Power: Astral Telepathy. These are earned for free once the psyker has acquired the discipline. Do these count towards the discipline mastery?

Comment: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/33469/mastering-telekinetic-discipline/33470#33470

Comment: Not sure this is exactly a duplicate, as this question specifically asks about the Special Power, which isn't mentioned in the other question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Rogue Trader errata](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=78&esem=4) states:

> Discipline Mastery (page 159):
>   The Basic Technique for a
>   Discipline does count towards the number of powers required
>   to acquire Discipline Mastery.

So my assumption is that the special power does not, but clearly the Basic Technique does.